# CONVERT VARCHAR-FLOAT

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query  is;

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
          WHEN 'A'='B' THEN 12456.00
          ELSE ''
      END
FROM TABLENAME
```

The format I need to write for this query to work;

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
          WHEN 'A'='B' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,12456.00)
          ELSE ''
       END
FROM TABLENAME
```

But i want this results ;

```
**IF 'A'='B' THEN 12.456,00
ELSE   ''**
```

My sample data:

| ID | VATColumn | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 2500 |
| 2 | yes | 4600 |
| 3 | no | 0 |

I want this results:

| ID | VATColumn | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 2.500,00 |
| 2 | yes | 4.600,00 |
| 3 | no | '' |

Comment: Please give some sample data, more details about the desired result.

Comment: Numeric display format isn't really something SQL is for.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I using MsSQL DB

Comment: The condition `WHEN 'A'='B'` will never be true.

Comment: In that condition, blank data should come

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not very much clear and specifically the condition, `WHEN 'A' = 'B'` is never going to be true but I assume you must have something logical in your real use case.

But keeping that apart, if I understood correctly then your main issue is regarding the format of the amount value. If so, then SQL Server has a built-in function [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that can help you to format your amount value in different cultures.

Here is an example of something like what you want to achieve:

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
          WHEN <<condition>> THEN REPLACE(FORMAT(12456.00,'C','pt-br'),'R$','')
          ELSE ''
       END
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Event if this answer is a way to do it, I would normally never let the database do some output formatting. It gives you no advantage because you must then give the format to the db depending on the result you want. So the format of the output should always be done by the application directly before output to the user and no where else.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea here is that you want to return a *string*, not a number.  Such formatting is often done at the application layer.  However, it can still be done in the database.

SQL Server has the [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function which does exactly this.  Several countries use `.` for the thousands separator and `,` for the decimal separator -- but not most English speaking countries.  `FORMAT()` takes a third argument which is a "culture", so you just need to use a culture that uses this format.

Then the code is:

```
select FORMAT(12456.00, '#,#.00', 'pt-br')
select FORMAT(12456.00, '#,#.00', 'es-es')
select FORMAT(12456.00, '#,#.00', 'de-de')
and so on
```

I would suggest using the actual culture argument for your locality.

You can have fun with this function and compare things like:

```
select FORMAT(12456.00, '#,#.00', 'pt-pt')
```